# Run JavaScript function only if user logged in - Django

Tags: javascript, django

So I have a function that checks a user's mailbox and a variable defined after it that sets the frequency of this function. However, I don't want the function to send unnecessary requests if the user isn't even signed in to the website. Where/how would I pass the if user.is_authenticated parameter to this code to check?

```
function checkMail() { // Checks for new mail in user's inbox
$.ajax({
   url: "/checkMail/",
   type: "POST",
   success: function(data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if(!obj.read){
                    $('#mailsquare').css('background-color', '#A80000');
                    $('.dropdown-menu').prepend('<li class="message" id="{{item.id}}">'+obj.newest.substring(0,30)+'</li>');
            } else {
                    $('#mailsquare').css('background-color', '#1b1b1b');
            }
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr.status); console.log(xhr.responseText); console.log(status); console.log(error); }
   });
}
var interval = setInterval(checkMail, 10000);  // Set interval for frequency of mail checks
```

Comment: how is login post handled? AJAX or conventional?

Comment: `var interval = setInterval(checkMail, 10000);` This is a very bad idea. Call the `checkMail()` function recursively using the ajax complete callback.

Comment: Brad, then how would the function execute the first time?

Comment: @Xonal Just call it once...

Comment: And login is handled conventionally.

Comment: @BradM Thanks. Can I ask why the current method is a bad idea?

Comment: @Xonal Because it doesn't consider the asynchronous nature of ajax requests. What happens if each request takes ~30 seconds? You will have approximately ~3 concurrent requests in a 30 second timespan, returning at different times. I've used that method before, and believe me, it causes odd problems that are hard to diagnose. Using callbacks ensures your code executes exactly as you have planned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your actual Django template, you can have a JavaScript block wrapped in a template tag that checks the user is logged in.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
         setInterval(checkMail, 10000);
     </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm looking for this, but inside the script, to make a variable.

Comment: Found the solution: `var auth = "{{request.user.is_authenticated}}"`

Comment: Thats will set true or false when page rendered, what if user logged out on other tab or other browser already ? the var auth =  true; is completely useless now, and either the page fail completely or some of the background task fails silently until this page gets refreshed. I don't have a solution ready but looking for a way to notify user that need to login again..